# How to get automatically page URL in ruby like CakePHP?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cakephp

I am beginner in Ruby on Rails. I have an `users_controller.rb` there have lots of `action` approximately 100 more. So it's hard to set in the routers. I want to automatically set action.

**Example:**

```
def abc
   render text: 'Hello World!'
end
...
...
def xyz
   render text: 'Bla Bla Bla'
end
```

I want my URL should be open this type

```
http://localhost:3000/users/abc
http://localhost:3000/users/xyz
http://localhost:3000/users/some-action..
```

No need to set any multi line URL path in routers.

Here below I was write in router. Bu that code not working:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

Please help me

Comment: you need this type of the things of all of your controller in the app ? or a particular controller

Comment: I think you should not use this kind of the things http://homakov.blogspot.in/2012/04/whitelist-your-routes-match-is-evil.html

Comment: What is `dnd`? ......

Comment: Sorry. Typing mistake. I just giving an example. :)

Comment: @sawa updated my question. Please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error I was getting using your code was :

```
You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method. (ArgumentError)
If you want to expose your action to both GET and POST, add `via: [:get, :post]` option.
```

On `Rails 4.2.5.2` and `ruby 2.3.0` the following works :

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))', via: [:get, :post]
```

Please note the `, via: [:get, :post]`.

Comment: Yes working fine. Previously i have set other path in routers. Is there affected or not after following `match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))', via: [:get, :post]`?

Comment: Rails routing works as follows : You have a `config\routes.rb` file. Rails will loop through each line, from top to bottom. If the current url matches the current line's route then Rails stops and uses that route, else it goes to the next line. Based on that, I guess you understand that if you put `match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))', via: [:get, :post]` ON TOP of your file then it will (almost) always match the route and so all lines below will be useless. The conclusion is : put this line AT THE BOTTOM of your `routes.rb`. More infos :  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html